# How can I reach another DigitalOcean droplet from docker with private networking?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I have two droplets.

- Host1: API,APP which runs with docker-compose
- Host2: Database runs on host without docker.

I have private networking enabled for both hosts. Without docker, I can ping from Host1 to Host2. How can I reach from `API` container to Host2 database with private network of DigitalOcean?

I know I can open external access from Host2 and use public IP but I want to keep it private don't want to pay for the traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding them to docker-swarm cluster. So they have access to each other.
Using Overlay network can solve the issue of multi-host docker container connectivity. THough if this is not what you want.  
But if you want to reach the host from inside the container try creating bridge or add route. If you are able to ping the host from container you just need route on host for reaching the host2 on DigiOcean private network

[a sample approach](https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248/3)

or just try to ping from a container attached to the default bridge, that should work as NAT.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not trying to reach from container on Host1 to Host1. I am trying to reach from container on Host1 to Host2 by private networking. Something like creating another network from my compose file to external Host2. I will look at docker-swarm option.

Comment: Hi, I tried on local network. If I'm able to ping the IP from the host I'm able to ping to it from the container running on the host. So can you try ping to the host2 from inside the container on host1. 
I's using Docker version 18.09.0

Comment: I tried but I can't make it work. The post you linked talks about connecting to host from the container. I want to connect to Host2 which is on different machine and have different IP address. Default bridge network can't connect from container to Host2

Comment: did you try to ping other IP (host2- private IP) from inside the container from Host1. If your container doesn;t have ping utility just use some small container for this test. It should work as NAT

Comment: My bad. Hos2 was denying the ping. It works. Thanks very much for your continous help. I really appreciate it.